# Get Text from GTK entry from a dialog

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I have a litte script thats create a settings dialog. After click OK I want to save the input from the user.

That is the call from the dialog:

```py
    def on_menubutton_click(self, widget):
        dialog = Settings(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            Settings.set_company_data(self)

        dialog.destroy()
```

That is the dialog

```py
class Settings(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Settings", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.set_default_size(300, 300)

        header = Gtk.Label()
        header.set_markup("<big><b>Settings</b></big>")
        header_company = Gtk.Label()
        header_company.set_markup("<b>Company</b>")

        companyname_label = Gtk.Label("Company")
        companyname_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        companyname_entry.set_text(Settings.COMPANY)

        companycontact_label = Gtk.Label("Name")
        companycontact_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        companycontact_entry.set_text(Settings.CONTACT)
#I put all in a grid
#Then I show the dialog

        self.show_all()
```

So what must I do to get in the on_menubutton_click method the entry text to save it?